# database password change results in broken website

Tags: linux, database, mariadb, lamp, change-password

I am running a website on amazon linux 2 (lamp server; database mariadb).

When I installed lamp, I think I did not assign a password for my db.
I can ssh login into my db with root/ nopassword.

Now, I would like to assign a password to / or change the password of my db.

Running the command

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

works flawlessly, at first sight.

I am able to log into my db then.

But: my website is completely down.
(All content unaivalable, just default header buttons, but they do not react).

So my assumption is: by setting that password for my db, something happens that leads to this 'unaivalability' of my db, for the website that runs on my server.

Thanks for any help or tip.

Andy

Comment: Sounds like your website was using the root account. MariaDB does support multiple users and for things like websites, a dedicated user/database for each website is recommended to avoid this and other incidental problems, like SQL injection being able to drop all databases.

Comment: thanks, any idea how I could change that? I mean, assigning a new user role, with password, with keeping this database alive/working..?

Comment: That's something you have to configure in your website and it depends on what you're using. Knowing what you use (e.g. Wordpress) would help answer that question.